# How does SQL Server store the information in Job Schedule Properties?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jobs

I know there is `SELECT * FROM msdb..sysjobschedules`, but that just shows the next time a job is scheduled to run.

I want to know how this is all determined and stored.  So where does it store the value for Recurs every Monday check box?

Comment: check out select * from msdb.dbo.sysschedules the system stored procedure `sp_add_schedule` updates or inserts into this table.

Comment: I think that information is stored in `msdb.dbo.sysschedules`. Check out the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every 20 minutes (this seems to NOT be configurable), the 'next run' information in [`sysjobschedules` is updated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188924.aspx) by looking at the information you can see in [`sysschedules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx).

You know how when you define a job you have to go through a slightly convoluted process of rather than just saying 'run this job every monday', instead defining a **schedule** that says that, and associating the job with the schedule? This is why - they have independent existences.

Answer (score 6):

And if you want to link the info in `sysschedules` to your job info:

```
use msdb;

select SYSJ.name, SYSS.* from sysjobs as SYSJ
inner join sysjobschedules as SYSJS on SYSJ.job_id = SYSJS.job_id
inner join sysschedules SYSS on SYSS.schedule_id = SYSJS.schedule_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Josien's answer, a nice post tying all the Job-related sys entities together and giving you a nice set of queries to look at the info therein: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/

I found it particularly helpful when I had a similar question and needed to build a report of all agent-jobs in our environment so that Dev's & other DBA's could look at them and provide context.  Cheers!